# Data Studio don't see Google Sheets formula results

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, looker-studio, google-finance

I have a problem with Google Data Studio.

I'm adding my sheet as a data source and.

There's one column in this sheet based on this formula:

```
=iferror(D2*index(query(GOOGLEFINANCE(CONCATENATE("CURRENCY:",C2,"PLN"),"price",B2-1, B2,"daily"),"select Col2"),2,1),"0")
```

This basically calculates the value in PLN based on the date in col B, currency in col C and the amount in col D.

Google Data studio should get the result of this formula and treat that as a value.

Instead, it doesn't see any value at all displaying 0 for the whole column.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix or work around that?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I'm aware of is to use the =IMPORTRANGE() function in Google Sheets. You can reference the same workbook you're in. Those values can then be accessed through Data Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I have a sheet that is made specifically for Data Studio to read and includes a column for month and a column for expenses. The expenses column contains an Index formula to return a dollar amount from a different sheet given the listed month. The numbers show correctly in sheets, but do not show in Data Studio.

Something that I found deep on another thread to solve this problem that worked for me is to change the format of the column in your sheet to 'Plain Text.' It seems to get pulled in Data Studio and recognizes that it is a number and shows correctly in my bar chart.